# How to Generate Date Series in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to generate a sequence of dates in Redshift. I can easily do it in PostgreSQL using the `generate_series()` function. This function works in Redshift, but only in the master node, so it fails when you have to use it in temporary tables on to apply some joins. I have found a way to generate date series in Redshift as follows, but I am looking for a more efficient way.

I consider an arbitrary table to get the row numbers and then based on the row numbers to generate the date series. Let's say that we want to generate a monthly date series from now and looking behind 200 months.

```
 SELECT
  DATEADD('month', -n, DATE_TRUNC('month', add_months(CURRENT_DATE,12))) AS gdate
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n FROM one_table LIMIT 200) n
```

[image]

Comment: Consider tools such as numbers tables, calendar tables, etc.  By persisting these concepts as tables, you just need to use a join.  This can lead to simplified code, sargable lookups *(on Redshift I tend to use DISTSTYLE ALL, ENCODING DELTA, etc, for fast access)*, and a host of incidental benefits *(such as persisting bank holiday information in calendar tables)*.  The use and merits of such tables is well documented on the Interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE ([which Redshift now supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html)).  You can generate the dates directly:

```
with recursive months (yyyymm, n) as (
      select date_trunc('month', current_date) as yyyymm, 1 as n
      union all
      select yyyymm - interval '1 month', n + 1
      from months m
      where n < 200
     )
select yyyymm
from months;
```

Comment: i'm getting an error "Interval values with month or year parts are not supported"

Comment: If `yyyymm - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` does not work, use `DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', yyyymm - INTERVAL '1 DAY')`, assuming `yyyymm` is always the first of the respective month.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive subquery (CTE/with clause):

```
with recursive numbers(NUMBER) as
(
select 1 UNION ALL
select NUMBER + 1 from numbers where NUMBER < 200
),
somedates(thedate) as 
(
select DATEADD('month', -NUMBER, DATE_TRUNC('month',CURRENT_DATE)) AS gdate
from numbers
)
```