# join 2 tables with different dates into one date column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two tables: a_table and b_table. They contain closing records and checkout records, that for each customer can be performed on different dates. I would like to combine these 2 tables together, so that there is only one date field, one customer field, one close and one check field.

a_table

```
time_modified         customer_name   
2021-05-03                Ben      
2021-05-08                Ben
2021-07-10                Jerry
```

b_table

```
time_modified account_id
2021-05-06        Ben
2021-07-08        Jerry
2021-07-12        Jerry
```

Expected result

```
date            account_id_a   close   check
2021-05-03          Ben          1       0
2021-05-06          Ben          0       1
2021-05-08          Ben          1       0
2021-07-08         Jerry         0       1
2021-07-10         Jerry         1       1
2021-07-12         Jerry         0       1
```

The query so far:

```
with a_table as ( 
    select rz.time_modified::date, rz.customer_name,
    case when rz.time_modified::date is not null then 1 else 0 end as close
    from schema.rz
                    ),
    b_table as (
    select bo.time_modified::date, bo.customer_name,
    case when bo.time_modified::date is not null then 1 else 0 end as check
    from schema.bo
                    )
SELECT (CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP  - (i * interval '1 day'))::date as date,
        a.*, b.*
FROM generate_series(1,2847) i 
left join a_table a  
    on a.time_modified = i.date 
left join b_table b
    on b.time_modified = i.date
```

The query above returns:

```
SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off the error you are getting is due to the use of the generate_series() function in a query where its results need to be combined with table data.  Generate_series() is a lead-node-only function and its results cannot be used on compute nodes.  You will need to generate the number series you desire in another way.  See [How to Generate Date Series in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101266/how-to-generate-date-series-in-redshift/69101475#69101475) for possible ways to do this.

I'm not sure I follow your query entirely but it seems like you want to UNION the tables and not JOIN them.  You haven't defined what rz and bo are so it is a bit confusing.  However UNION and some calculation for close and check seems like the way to go

Answer (score 2):

you just need to do a union rather than a join.
Join merges two tables into one where union adds the second table to the first